Who's responsible for the comments like "This question is similar to … If you believe it’s different, please edit the question …"?
Under one of my questions, I saw the following comment from the user "user405662": "This question is similar to … If you believe it’s different, please edit the question …". That comment was inappropriate and able to mislead other members who read my question. I flagged it but moderators rejected my flag.
The user Barmar said the presence of that comment is not someone's fault but fault of Stack Exchange itself. And he advised me to complain about it here in Meta.
So, is it possible to do something in order that SE not be at fault for creating the comments like that any more in future?
P.S.: the screenshot of the comments:


Update:
After thinking, I disagree it's SE's fault. It's fault of the user who considers the question as a duplicate. SE just makes him responsible for it by writing the comment on his behalf. The canned comment makes its user be ready to explain to others why he's thinking it's a dup and if he can't, that means the user abuses his powers.

This is not Meta (with a capital M) this is EL&U meta (lowercase m). I guess you don't pay attention to anyone else's question because if you did, you would know that you're not the first to be hit with a VTC as a duplicate. Every time someone votes to close a question as a duplicate that same comment appears. It does not depend on the user, it depends on the system which jumps into action. It's automatic. A "canned" comment is something that is pre-written. Click on the link that Barmar posted and if you're brave enough, complain there.

I did not generate that comment, it popped up automatically. The comment was changed about a year ago, but this question is an exact  duplicate of your older one.

@Mari-LouA "Brave enough" ??? Are we talking about fighting with hooligans? Saying an opinion is about brain, not braveness.

I should have deleted that phrase, it was borne out of bitterness. Nothing to do with you, I have bad history with Meta.

Your question was initially formulated as a question about a certain kind of comments. The answer to that question is: the wording of the comment is 'canned' (it is built into the setup of the site), but what triggers its appearance is that somebody (a human being) has voted to close your question as a duplicate. After the 'update', it turns out that what you are really complaining about is the fact that people have voted to close some of your questions as duplicates. Whether such votes are warranted is a question-specific matter.

Note that there already are several mechanisms for countering unjustified votes to close. A single vote is not enough to close a question; if it is unjustified, chances are that there won't be enough votes to actually close it. When somebody votes to close a question, a queue is generated to review whether it really needs to be closed. If a question is closed, it can be reopened, if enough people think that it should. You can help that process work as intended by explaining how your question is different, rather than dismissing other contributors opinions about it.
